# .Net Core Web API can't add route to controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got a brand new .NET Core Web API application that I'm working on.  I've generated a new controller, which added the Route attribute to the Controller, so the HTTP Method is the parameter.  I want to change it so the ActionName is part of the route, but putting a Route attribute on the action doesn't seem to be working.  So my controller is set up like this currently:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Spells")]
public class SpellsController : Controller
{
    private readonly Spellbook3APIContext _context;

    public SpellsController(Spellbook3APIContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Spells
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Spell> GetSpells()
    {
        return _context.Spells;
    }
}
```

I want to do it this way:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class SpellsController : Controller
{
    private readonly Spellbook3APIContext _context;

    public SpellsController(Spellbook3APIContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Spells
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Spells/GetSpells")]
    public IEnumerable<Spell> GetSpells()
    {
        return _context.Spells;
    }
}
```

But when I put that, it doesn't work.  I just get a 404.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
 [HttpGet("GetSpells")]
 public IEnumerable<Spell> GetSpells()
 {
     return _context.Spells;
 }
```

Comment: That's still 404ing for me

Comment: updated more code, does this one work? ...added the route at the class level

Comment: Sadly no. :(  Also you're missing a square bracket on the right of [Route("/GetSpells")] but that wasn't my issue

Comment: try adding the route to the httpget parameter? and make sure the class has the route attribute

Comment: Aha! That did it! Thank you!